# Excel - Create a list of unique values with their max dates when a third value is true

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Working in 2013. I am hoping to achieve this using only formulas. I am starting with:

```
Part     Date          Bool
1        2/14/2020     1
1        10/22/2019    0
1        7/27/2020     1
2        8/26/2020     1
2        9/10/2020     0
2        10/06/2020    1
3        10/23/2020    0
```

What I what to end with:

```
Part     Date
1        7/27/2020
2        10/06/2020
```

I know how my statement would look in an SSMS query:

```
SELECT Part, Max(Date)
FROM Table
WHERE Bool = 1
GROUP BY Part
```

Currently I am working with a really ugly setup, where I first create a column ("Late Parts Only") that has a formula to isolate parts that are tied to at least 1 positive bool:

```
=IF(TableX@[Bool] = 1, TableX@[Part], "")
```

Next I am trying to use an array-index to extract unique parts from that list:

```
{=INDEX{TableX@[Late Parts Only], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($U$2:U2, TableX@[Late Parts Only]), 0))}
```

^^Where "$U$2:U2" is the header of the column the forumla exists in. [I used this page as reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list)

Which produces a usable list ("Unique Part List"). However, extracting the max date is where I get hung up:

```
=MAX(IF(TableX@[Unique Part List] = TableX@[Part], TableX@[Date]))
```

But this results in a lot of "1/0/1900" dates, because the rows do not line up absolutely.

[My current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyf6J.png)

Comment: Sounds like this can  be solved easily by using a power query.

Comment: Unfortunately, Power Query is not an option for this solution, due to system admin restrictions. I need to be able to solve this within excel cell functions alone. Although, yes, that would make things easier.

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: To be honest I am not super familiar with pivot tables. I started looking into it already after I saw your comment about power query. Although I don't quite see how I will get the final result I am looking for, even with pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data occupies column A to C, in E2 put :

```
=A2
```

then in F2 :

```
=B2
```

then

in E3 :

```
=IF($C3=0,IF($A2=$A3,E2,IF($C3=0,"",A3)),A3)
```

in F3 :

```
=IF($C3=0,IF($A2=$A3,F2,IF($C3=0,"",B3)),B3)
```

in G3 :

```
=IF($A4<>$A3,E3,"")
```

in H3 :

```
=IF($A4<>$A3,F3,"")
```

Select E3:I3 and drag downwards. your result shall be in column H&I.

Kindly share if it works/not.